# iOS clicks through status bar after hiding

Tags: ios, uikit

I added these 2 keys to hide status bar:

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

It works great, but I realize that when clicking on the status bar area, we can actually click through the view underneath.

I have a UICollectionView behind the status bar area, and I can actually click on the collection cell. In the picture below, Cell #12 is right above Cell #16, and we can actually tap on upper right corner to trigger `didSelectCell(atIndexPath`.

How do I disable this "click through" behavior, and bring back the "auto scroll to top" behavior when tapping on status bar?

[image]

Comment: yeah, but the status bar is too distracting from my game content, especially when I have several label right below it in some screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the UICollectionView top constraint to be constrained to the parent view safeAreaTopAnchor instead of the parent view topAnchor. That way you have the UICollectionView out of the way of the statusbar

Comment: it worked. The autoscroll is not working though, but i guess there's no way to fix that without the status bar

Comment: Awesome but I don't think that should affect scrolling behavior. Maybe you edit your question with a code sample.

Comment: scrolling is gone. i guess scrolling only works when user actually tap on the status bar

Comment: I think it's fine. it's only an issue with iPhone X's top left and top right corner. On older phones, the status bar is not even there